# Reports with MultiParameter Values - SSRS Reports not working- FIPS ISSUE

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Reports work fine when browsed from the Report server,but when opened from the application I see the below error

[image]

Machine key is already added to both Report Server and Report manager web.config files.

I would like to have FIPS enabled and make reports work.

Currently using Windows Server 2012 R2 . Please suggest if you know of any windows updates that resolves this issue.

Comment: Yes, I did. Machine key is already added to the web.config file. But still seeing the FIPS issue when browsing the reports.

Comment: In the log files when I searched with "error" I see the below :
xception caught instantiating TERADATA report server extension: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Teradata.Client.Provider, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=76b417ee2e04956c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Can you provide a sample set of the multiple parameter? Are you passing it in from a URL? If so, can you provide just the part of the URL with the parameter values?

Comment: Populating mutlivalues drop down from a dataset. I am passing databasename and database server name on the fly.

Comment: How are you passing the parameters? Can you post an example of what fails?

Comment: Found that the issue is with web server but not the report server. So I tried to add <enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false" /> in the web.config. Restart the IIS but it does not take into effect.  Any suggestions on how to disable FIPS other than changing the value from 1 to 0 ? Thanks!